# Como alterar para propriedade android:fontFamily="casual" em um textView dinamicamente?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, textview

Gostaria de saber como faço para alterar a font para casual no meu textView através de código java.

```
TextView text1 = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

Quero mudar a font do text1 para casual (`android:fontFamily="casual"`), mas não sei como fazer isso através de código java. Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É simples, faz o seguinte:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.create("casual", Typeface.NORMAL);
text1.setTypeface(tf);
```

onde text1 é o seu `TextView`, "casual" é a fonte que deseja.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Perfeito amigo vou dar uma testada agora....

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente - Obs! Eu errei na digitação da pergunta.... Eu escrevi ``android:famalyFont="casual"`` mas o correto é ``android:fontFamily="casual"``.... Mas já que estamos no assunto então me corrija se eu tiver errado, mas essa propriedade é para API16+ estou certo?

Comment: Tanto o `Typeface.create()`, quanto `textview.setTypeface()`, estão desde a API 1. de acordo com [Typeface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface#create(java.lang.String,%20int)) e [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface))